# Why does my pointer arithmetic fail in this array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Resource
typedef struct _Resource Resource;

// ResourceBuffer
typedef struct _ResourceBuffer ResourceBuffer;
ResourceBuffer *resource_buffer_new(int);
ResourceBuffer *resourceBuffer;
void resource_buffer_test();

struct _ResourceBuffer {
    char *id;
    int size;
    Resource **buffer;
};

struct _Resource {
    int id;
    char *status;
};

Resource *resource_new(int i) {
    Resource *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    r->status = "groovy";
    r->id = i;
    return r;
}

void resource_buffer_test() {

    printf("buftest has buf as %d\n",resourceBuffer->buffer);
    printf("buftest has drefbuf as %d\n",*(resourceBuffer->buffer));

    Resource *bp[resourceBuffer->size];
    bp[0] = *(resourceBuffer->buffer+0);
    bp[1] = *(resourceBuffer->buffer+1); 
    bp[2] = *(resourceBuffer->buffer+2);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("address is %d\n", bp[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //printf("ptrBuffer r%d is %s\n", i, (*((Resource **)(resourceBuffer->buffer)+i))->status);
        printf("Buffer r%d is %s\n", bp[i]->id, bp[i]->status);
    }
}

ResourceBuffer *resource_buffer_new(int bufferSize) {
    ResourceBuffer *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    Resource *b[bufferSize];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        b[i] = resource_new(i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        printf("res address is %d\n", b[i]);
        printf("pnt address is %d\n", &b[i]);
    }
    printf("b address is %d\n", b);
    r->buffer = b;
    printf("buffer set to %d\n", r->buffer);
    r->size = bufferSize;
    r->id = "foo";
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // initialize buffer
    resourceBuffer = resource_buffer_new(3);
    resource_buffer_test();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output is:

```
res address is 36585520
pnt address is 783569984
res address is 36585552
pnt address is 783569992
res address is 36585584
pnt address is 783570000
b address is 783569984
buffer set to 783569984
buftest has buf as 783569984
buftest has drefbuf as 36585520
address is 36585520
address is 36585552
address is 36585520
Buffer r0 is groovy
Buffer r1 is groovy
Buffer r0 is groovy
```

What confuses me is the last 6 lines... Why in `resource_buffer_test()` do `b[0]` and `b[2]` end up pointing to the Resource struct r0?

For some reason this part fails:

```
bp[0] = *(resourceBuffer->buffer+0);
bp[1] = *(resourceBuffer->buffer+1); 
bp[2] = *(resourceBuffer->buffer+2);
```

Where `*(resourceBuffer->buffer+2)` somehow ends up pointing back to the first element in the array, rather than the third.

Why does this happen? What causes the C pointer arithmetic to reset `*(resourceBuffer->buffer+2)` back to `*(resourceBuffer->buffer+0)`?

What is really odd (to me anyway)... is that when I change the `resource_buffer_new` function to look like this:

```
ResourceBuffer *resource_buffer_new(int bufferSize) {
    ResourceBuffer *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    Resource *b[bufferSize+1];
```

(note the `*b[bufferSize+1]`) -- then it works as expected..

Why do I need to have extra room in my buffer array for the pointer arithmetic to work?

Comment: Maybe try paring down your code to something a little more digestible? Also, have you tried walking through the code with a debugger?

Comment: sorry i tried to pair it down as much as i could while retaining any complexity that might be causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r->buffer = b;` is your problem. `b` is a local variable that goes out of scope once you return from `resource_buffer_new()`.  If you made `b` static or allocated it, it would be ok.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. my goal here was to point to an array that would have a different size for each ResourceBuffer struct. I decided to use a linked list instead